# How do I stop my Xbox 360 controller making "device plugged in" sound whenever I fire?

Tags: controllers, windows, windows-8, dead-space-3

Whenever I fire a weapon or stomp, my computer emits the new device sound and disables my controller for a split second, meaning I fire a shot or two on an automatic rifle and then return to stance. This only happens with stomp or shooting while zoomed in. It doesn't happen with running, or striking.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying @Cole's own answer:

> One of the reasons
>   this could have been happening was because I was using and extension
>   cord that is built into my keyboard. I also switched from a USB 2.0
>   header to a 3.0 header.

Answer (score 1):

Further testing I have done myself (as I had the same issue but with Windows 7) is that this issue is fixed by not using an extension (in this case I had the controller plugged into my keyboard). There is no difference depending on whether a USB 2 or USB 3 header is used.